# Excel VBA- Dynamic formula returning zero value for range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to have vba create a formula for two ranges within the same data set, as input into variables lastRow and lastRow2.  However, when I try to create and calculate the formula, instead of getting the value of the last cell I get a zero.  Offending code below:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastRow2 As Long
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow2 = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


...



    'Calculate ATRT 2014 at cell B4
    Range("B6").Formula = "=(SUM(J11:J" & lastRow & ")/ SUM(I11:I" & lastRow & "))"
    Range("E6").Formula = "=(SUM(U11:U" & lastRow2 & ")/ SUM(T11:T" & lastRow2 & "))"
    Range("H6").Formula = "=E6-B6"
```

Running this gets two formulas: =(SUM(J11:J0)/ sum(I11:I0)) and =(SUM(U11:U0)/ SUM(T11:T0)).  Why is the end of the range a zero???

Comment: Heh that's what I asked in your other question. Are the ranges all on the same sheet?

Comment: Yes, the ranges are on the same sheet, in the same table.  1 table, but two different ranges

Comment: Hmm are you running the macro while the desired sheet is active? If so, then I am stumped. Unless you didn't really mean columns A/M... Edit: huh. Even if the column is empty, it should still be at least 1.... we need more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what is happening if you are not defining which worksheet the range() and row() objects are on so VBA is guessing and probably guessing incorrectly. Try adding a worksheet object and then defining all the ranges and rows to use be on that worksheet.

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastRow2 As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRow2 = ws.Range("M" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


'...



'Calculate ATRT 2014 at cell B4
ws.Range("B6").Formula = "=(SUM(J11:J" & lastRow & ")/ SUM(I11:I" & lastRow & "))"
ws.Range("E6").Formula = "=(SUM(U11:U" & lastRow2 & ")/ SUM(T11:T" & lastRow2 & "))"
ws.Range("H6").Formula = "=E6-B6"
```

Comment: That's what I thought before I realized that it should end in at least a 1. Something else is going on.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the 0 was weird too. But when I actually ran this code it returned correctly. Without actually having the workbook it's hard to say what is happening. One option the asker could try is to see what that range thinks is parent is `debug.print Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).parent.name` and see if that its actually the worksheet they think it should be.

Comment: Just checked, it's the same worksheet.  I tried running it front to back with my old code (not making changes listed above) and the first formula (outputting on B6) works but the second formula (outputting on E6) did not and has the same error.  

The issue seems to be with lastRow2, since trying to autofill to it leads to go upwards.

Comment: Edit: Solved the issue, the problem was that the data starts out as separate tables and then are combined, but I was creating the variable on a blank field pre-combining.